# NO SPST vs SPDT

Tags: relay

As I am trying to find the most suitable relay, I was wondering if is it better to use SPST or SPDT. Currently I am using just NO SPST and it seems to work well, but are they any advantages to use SPDT instead?

I had this idea when I saw the animation *http://www.theorycircuit.com/spdt-relay-dpdt-relay/*.

I do understand that SPDT is a double throw and can have two circuit paths instead of SPST, where there can be only one. But what are the advantages of using SPDT for one path only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLgee.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Various relay contact options.*

> But what are the advantages of using SPDT for one path only.

Reasons for using a double-throw relay contact arrangement when only an NO contact is required includes:

- Standardisation for bill of materials. Only one relay needs to be stocked.
- Potential for future modifications where an NC contact is required.
- Due to some other requirements (unusual coil voltage, size, pinout, relay base, etc.) only DT configurations are available.

Generally there are no disadvantages other than cost. A single-throw relay should be cheaper to manufacture.